# How to prevent squirrels from damaging pipe boots?

Tags: roof, pest-control

I have a few pipe boots on my roof that squirrels like to munch on. I'm not sure why but it creates a lot of work for me.

[image]

How can I prevent this from happening again once I fix the boot? This is the second time its happened and I'm sure will continue. I was thinking barb wire around it but I'd prefer a more aesthetic solution.

Comment: Is that a lead roof vent flashing??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Metal window screen and black spray paint.

I have squirrels that eat my resin lawn furniture. I swear they are as bright as Stephen Hawking and more destructive than chain saws.

Answer (score 4):

Do not allow squirrels or any animals access to roof by eliminating trees which are less than 6 feet away.

Comment: A bit drastic, no?